# Using Wordnet Gem - Wordnet::Lexicon.new gives NameError

Tags: ruby, nlp, wordnet

I just installed the [wordnet gem](https://github.com/ged/ruby-wordnet) and [wordnet-defaultdb](http://rubygems.org/gems/wordnet-defaultdb) gem
. When i try to create a ne lexicon using the WordNet::Lexicon.new command in I get Name Error. Lexicon does not show up as a subclass of WordNet either.

I have spent a whole day trying to figure this out. Is this an installation issue? If it is can someone guide me or point me to guide on how to install the wordnet gem.

I'm using MRI-1.9.3

Comment: If you can paste the exact error message you are receiving, that might help others diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this similar issue using the WordNet gem. The wordnet-defaultdb gem relies on two dependencies: sqlite3, which should be standard, and wordnet itself. Add gem "wordnet", "~> 1.0.0" to your gemfile and the wordnet-defaultdb gem should now be working fine.